# Android startActivity

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, kotlin

Есть `Fragment` и на нем кнопки, которым нужно определить слушатель, который бы открывал разные `Activity`. К примеру:

```
bt_statistics.setOnClickListener {
    startActivity(Intent(this, StatisticsActivity::class.java))
}
```

Я так понял, что из фрагмента нужно вызвать метод `Activity`, который и будет запускать `Activity`, но как?

Comment: C Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference разобрался.

Comment: Фрагмент и сам прекрасно умеет запускать активити, был бы интент. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

Comment: val intent : Intent = Intent(this.activity , StatisticsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)  - решение моего вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь:

```
startActivity(Intent(this, StatisticsActivity::class.java))
```

Первым параметром вместо контекста вы передаёте сам фрагмент, который контекстом не является.

Вызывайте либо так:

```
startActivity(Intent(context, StatisticsActivity::class.java))
```

Либо так:

```
startActivity(Intent(activity, StatisticsActivity::class.java))
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного поправлю Peter Samokhin,
startActivity(Intent(**getActivity(),** StatisticsActivity::class.java))